# Puppet-lint configuration file

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to disable checks in puppet-lint using a configuration file as it is in rubocop? The configuration file should be a txt file, a json file or other formats?

Comment: on the terminal you can disable rules with a command as:  'puppet-lint --no-quoted_booleans-check --no-class_inherits_from_params_class-check --no-80chars-check

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the file is called `.puppet-lint.rc` and should look like this:

```
--fail-on-warnings
--relative
--no-class_inherits_from_params_class-check
--no-documentation-check
--no-single_quote_string_with_variables-check
```

It's a list of arguments that you would normally pass as command line arguments. For all checks see [documentation](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/).